# What do two backward slashes in file path mean?

Tags: windows

What exactly do two backward slashes in file path mean? Eg. `\\some\path\to\file`

I often see file paths like this on Windows systems. I think they have something to do with network locations, but then how to translate this path to IP address?

Comment: I thought the question was quite clear and started a rather reasonable answer, only to be notified I could not post the answer.  Perhaps its a duplicate question as well, who knows, but how is it not clear?

Comment: @DavidPostill: please what is unclear on this question?

Comment: Reopened........

Answer (score 2):

File paths shown with 2 backslashes are for network shares. For example `\\192.168.0.2\MyShareFolder` or `\\MyNAS\MyShareFolder`. You can find more detailed information on [Wikipedia's article on shared resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_resource).

Using the Windows command prompt, run the command `nslookup ServerName` to get the IP address of the respective server: E.g. `nslookup MyNAS` would reveal that it has the IP of `192.168.0.2` in the example above.